# Rotating an edge around another without stretching edges

Tags: edges

How do I go about rotating an edge around another while keeping all edge lengths the same? [image: screenshot]

On the included screenshot, I'd like to move the orange edge freely around the white edge without any edges changing lengths. So, the white edge should simply be the pivot.

Comment: put the 3D cursor on the white edge and choose the 3D cursor as pivot point?

Comment: I should clarify that I only want the orange edge to move. If I put the cursor on the white and rotate with cursor as pivot, the white edge moves upwards.

Comment: It shouldn't. On which axis are you rotating ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Pivot Point menu, select Active Element, then do the rotation (around the Y axis in this case, so <kbd>R</kbd>/<kbd>Y</kbd>)

The Active Element is the last selected element, it appears in white instead of yellow.

[image]

Comment: Amazing, it works! I tried using the menu that pops up at the bottom of the screen after doing a rotate, but there was no "Active Element" there. Maybe they should do something about that. Glad you knew where it was actually located.

Comment: I'm glad that works for you! Moonboot's comment should work too. Anyway, I don't think the Pivot Point should be an Operator setting ("the menu that pops up") as you suggest, because it's relevant which mindset you're in, not which tool you're in. But maybe it's just me ;)